# Make - how to copy two different files to different locations

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm not familiar to makefile syntax. I would like to copy 2 files to different locations.

```
DST    := c:/A/a.txt \
          c:/B/b.txt \

SRC    := c:/src/1.bin \
          c:/src/2.bin \

all: $(DST)

$(DST): $(SRC)
    cp -f $< $@
```

The code above doesn't work because $< is the first prerequisite. Uses $^ also incorrect. How I can achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is that there's no easy way to automatically create rules UNLESS there's some way to match up the source and destination via filename: they have some common stem.  If the source file and destination file are both completely arbitrary and have no relationship other than their position in the `SRC` and `DST` variables then there's no straightforward way to write the makefile.

Comment: You either need to use very fancy tricks such as HarcoreHenry suggests, or else just write out the rules by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what this expands to:

```
c:/A/a.txt c:/B/b.txt : c:/src/1.bin c:/src/2.bin
    cp -f $< $@
```

This means that `a.txt` *and* `b.txt` depend on both `1.bin` *and* `2.bin`, and they have the same recipe, which is obviously not what you want.

If you want to do a generic list mapping, where element n of list1 maps to element n of list 2, this becomes a bit messy, and you would have to do something like this:

```
DST    := c:/A/a.txt \
          c:/B/b.txt \

SRC    := c:/src/1.bin \
          c:/src/2.bin \

$(foreach IDX,$(shell seq 1 $(words $(DST))),\
    $(eval \
       $(word $(IDX),$(DST)) : $(word $(IDX),$(SRC))))

$(DST):
    cp -f $< $@
```

Of course this has a sharp stick attached -- if you add any dependency explicitly to `$(DST)`, then make will populate `$<` with that instead of your variable.   (Also note I used `seq` in the `shell` command -- not sure if this will work with your setup as you seem to be using windows...)

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any usable relationship between the source and dest files, and you prefer to use a more standard/less tricky set of rules than those suggested in the other answer, you'll just have to write out the dependencies by hand, something like this:

```
DST    := c:/A/a.txt \
          c:/B/b.txt \

all: $(DST)

$(DST) :
          cp -f $< $@

c:/A/a.txt : c:/src/1.bin
c:/B/b.txt : c:/src/2.bin
```

This does require you to duplicate the DST values (once in the variable and once as a target) but you only need to write the rule one time.

There is one other possibility, which is tricky but doesn't rely on external shell programs like `seq`.  It will require you to define the relationship via variables AND it will require all the destination files to be on the same drive.  It would look like this:

```
DST_/A/a.txt := c:/src/1.bin
DST_/B/b.txt := c:/src/2.bin
```

(there can be no other variables in your makefile that start with `DST_`; choose some unique prefix if that's not good enough).

Then the rest of the makefile would be:

```
DST := $(foreach V,$(filter DST_%,$(.VARIABLES)),c:$($V))

all: $(DST)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(DST) : c:% : $$(DST_$$*)
          cp -f $< $@
```

(fair warning, I didn't actually test this so there may be some typos :) )

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you weren't on Windows.  Drive letters just don't mix well with make.